# Angular Material popup alignment issue with first time load

Tags: angular, angular-material

When user click on popup button as a first time, I am getting alignment issue like this:

[image: First time look]

When click on second time, it look fine. How can I solve this? is it require to add any delay? or needs any refresh approach?

Actual:

[image: Second time]

Code :

```
 openDialog(templateRef: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>) {
        this.addClinicDialogRef = this.dialog.open(templateRef, {
            height: '80%',
            width: '80%',
            panelClass: ['add-clinic-dialog'],
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console first time?

Comment: No, getting no error

Comment: Can you please add photo how dialog looks when you open second time.

Comment: Are you opening dialog on button click or page load?

Comment: Button click to show the search form

Comment: Can you add your dialog open code?

Comment: Can you add your dialog  configuration and data loading code?

Comment: code added for reference on popup open